# Network connection intermittently dropping but WiFi staying connected on macOS

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

**The Problem:**
The network connection on my 16" MacBook Pro is intermittently dropping out every 3-6 minutes for around 10-30 seconds. The WiFi remains connected and other devices connected to the same WiFi are able to access the internet during the outage.

**Investigating Further:** I've been looking through the Console trying to pinpoint anything that could lead me to a cause of the problem but I'm not sure if the messages that are output during the outage are causes or effects. There doesn't seem to be a critical event that happens between the connection working and then dropping out.

```
default 16:41:08.735552+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q65412] Received UDP DNS Message 85 bytes from <private>:53 to <private>:64169 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.735584+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q65412] DNS Response (85) (flags 8180) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD RA:<private> 2/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.735639+0000    mDNSResponder   mDNSCoreReceiveCacheCheck: rescuing RR <private>
default 16:41:08.735663+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13765->Q65412] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, Addr) RESULT ADD interface 0: (mortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.735711+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13765->Q65412] AnswerQuestionByFollowingCNAME: 0x7fec5a805eb8 <private> (Addr) following CNAME referral 0 for <private>
default 16:41:08.735842+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13765->Q36367] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec5a805eb8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (Addr)
default 16:41:08.735891+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13766->Q17449] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, AAAA) RESULT ADD interface 0: (mortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.735908+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13766->Q17449] AnswerQuestionByFollowingCNAME: 0x7fec5700e2b8 <private> (AAAA) following CNAME referral 0 for <private>
default 16:41:08.735987+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13766->Q50040] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec5700e2b8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (AAAA)
default 16:41:08.736056+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13765->Q65412] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, Addr) RESULT ADD interface 0: (immortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.736105+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q17449] Sent UDP DNS Message 48 bytes from <private>:62749 to <private>:53 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.736125+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q17449] DNS Query (48) (flags 0100) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD:<private> 0/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.743644+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q17449] Received UDP DNS Message 97 bytes from <private>:53 to <private>:62749 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.743675+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q17449] DNS Response (97) (flags 8180) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD RA:<private> 2/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.743702+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q17449] mDNSCoreReceiveResponse ignoring <private>
default 16:41:08.743722+0000    mDNSResponder   mDNSCoreReceiveCacheCheck: rescuing RR <private>
default 16:41:08.743746+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13766->Q17449] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, AAAA) RESULT ADD interface 0: (immortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.743855+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13765] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, Addr) STOP PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:08.743940+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13766] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, AAAA) STOP PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:08.840596+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 6 children, _eventMask=0x4c _childEventMask=0x46 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:08.848884+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 4 children, _eventMask=0x42 _childEventMask=0x42 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:08.898961+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, Addr) START PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:08.899100+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q10255] InitDNSConfig: Setting StopTime on the uDNS question 0x7fec5780c2b8 <private> (Addr)
default 16:41:08.899125+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767->Q10255] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec5780c2b8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (Addr)
default 16:41:08.899410+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, AAAA) START PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:08.899498+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] InitDNSConfig: Setting StopTime on the uDNS question 0x7fec578030b8 <private> (AAAA)
default 16:41:08.899557+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768->Q21526] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec578030b8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (AAAA)
default 16:41:08.899863+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q10255] Sent UDP DNS Message 41 bytes from <private>:52359 to <private>:53 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.899887+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q10255] DNS Query (41) (flags 0100) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD:<private> 0/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.900026+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] Sent UDP DNS Message 41 bytes from <private>:49680 to <private>:53 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.900047+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] DNS Query (41) (flags 0100) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD:<private> 0/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.927575+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q10255] Received UDP DNS Message 71 bytes from <private>:53 to <private>:52359 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.927608+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q10255] DNS Response (71) (flags 8180) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD RA:<private> 2/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.927660+0000    mDNSResponder   mDNSCoreReceiveCacheCheck: rescuing RR <private>
default 16:41:08.927685+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767->Q10255] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, Addr) RESULT ADD interface 0: (immortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.927705+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767->Q10255] AnswerQuestionByFollowingCNAME: 0x7fec5780c2b8 <private> (Addr) following CNAME referral 0 for <private>
default 16:41:08.927855+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767->Q25396] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec5780c2b8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (Addr)
default 16:41:08.927907+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768->Q21526] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, AAAA) RESULT ADD interface 0: (immortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.927928+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768->Q21526] AnswerQuestionByFollowingCNAME: 0x7fec578030b8 <private> (AAAA) following CNAME referral 0 for <private>
default 16:41:08.928051+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768->Q44848] GetServerForQuestion: 0x7fec578030b8 DNS server (0x7fec5c9095a0) <private>:53 (Penalty Time Left 0) (Scope None:0x0:-1) for <private> (AAAA)
default 16:41:08.928231+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767->Q10255] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, Addr) RESULT ADD interface 0: (immortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.928283+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] Sent UDP DNS Message 32 bytes from <private>:49680 to <private>:53 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.928368+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] DNS Query (32) (flags 0100) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD:<private> 0/0/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.930495+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] Received UDP DNS Message 105 bytes from <private>:53 to <private>:49680 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.930526+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] DNS Response (105) (flags 8180) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD RA:<private> 1/1/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.930552+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] mDNSCoreReceiveResponse ignoring <private>
default 16:41:08.930571+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] mDNSCoreReceiveResponse ignoring <private>
default 16:41:08.953897+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] Received UDP DNS Message 82 bytes from <private>:53 to <private>:49680 via en0 (0x6)
default 16:41:08.953934+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] DNS Response (82) (flags 8180) RCODE: NoErr (0) RD RA:<private> 0/1/0 <private>
default 16:41:08.953967+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q21526] mDNSCoreReceiveResponse ignoring <private>
default 16:41:08.953999+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768->Q21526] DNSServiceQueryRecord(<private>, AAAA) RESULT ADD interface 0: (mortal)<private>
default 16:41:08.954145+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13767] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, Addr) STOP PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:08.954225+0000    mDNSResponder   [R13768] DNSServiceQueryRecord(1D000, 0, <private>, AAAA) STOP PID[3330](Spotify Helper)
default 16:41:09.120253+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 5 children, _eventMask=0x63 _childEventMask=0x63 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:09.128262+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 4 children, _eventMask=0x60 _childEventMask=0x62 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:09.497452+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 6 children, _eventMask=0x4c _childEventMask=0x46 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:09.563065+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 6 children, _eventMask=0x44 _childEventMask=0x46 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:09.766386+0000    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.google.GoogleDrive.FinderSyncAPIExtension(501)>:7107] Death sentinel fired!
default 16:41:09.771044+0000    runningboardd   [xpcservice<com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync(501)>:7108] Death sentinel fired!
default 16:41:09.788458+0000    launchservicesd QUITTING: pid=7107 asn=0x-0x8d08d foreground=0 wasFront=0
default 16:41:09.789786+0000    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | for app:Backup and Sync from Google, _appTrackingState = 2
default 16:41:09.790343+0000    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 301-135-465 (target:xpcservice<com.google.GoogleDrive.FinderSyncAPIExtension(501)>) from originator 135
default 16:41:09.790642+0000    CommCenter  #I handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application exited: <private>
default 16:41:09.790523+0000    launchservicesd QUITTING: pid=7108 asn=0x-0x8e08e foreground=0 wasFront=0
default 16:41:09.792264+0000    loginwindow -[PersistentAppsSupport applicationQuit:] | for app:Core Sync Helper, _appTrackingState = 2
default 16:41:09.793097+0000    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 301-135-467 (target:xpcservice<com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync(501)>) from originator 135
default 16:41:09.793436+0000    CommCenter  #I handleLSNotitifcation_sync: Application exited: <private>
default 16:41:09.872263+0000    runningboardd   Removing process: [xpcservice<com.google.GoogleDrive.FinderSyncAPIExtension(501)>:7107]
default 16:41:09.872275+0000    runningboardd   Removing process: [xpcservice<com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync(501)>:7108]
default 16:41:09.872903+0000    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [xpcservice<com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync(501)>:7108]
default 16:41:09.877202+0000    runningboardd   Removing assertions for terminated process: [xpcservice<com.google.GoogleDrive.FinderSyncAPIExtension(501)>:7107]
error   16:41:09.904119+0000    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 301-135-465 (target:xpcservice<com.google.GoogleDrive.FinderSyncAPIExtension(501)>)
error   16:41:09.904154+0000    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item 301-135-467 (target:xpcservice<com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync(501)>)
default 16:41:10.279186+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 6 children, _eventMask=0x4c _childEventMask=0x46 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:10.293754+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 3 children, _eventMask=0x42 _childEventMask=0x42 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:10.441988+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 5 children, _eventMask=0x63 _childEventMask=0x63 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:10.451584+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 4 children, _eventMask=0x60 _childEventMask=0x62 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
error   16:41:10.695738+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:10.695785+0000    Spotify  Open failed
error   16:41:10.700282+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:10.700304+0000    Spotify  Open failed
default 16:41:10.713502+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photosanalysis:F8617C:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.714210+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.security.syspolicy.measure:BA87DC:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.714823+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent.app-discovery:96F7F2:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.715271+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.fullanalysis:F250D3:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.715681+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.knowledgestore.sync:2809B6:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.716125+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.suggestd.persist-stats:8AC3EA:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.716530+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.syncdefaultsd:463093:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.716955+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.photolibraryd.curatedlibraryprocessing:F66771:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.717331+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.revisiond.requeue_chunking:B96F5F:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.717709+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.revisiond.CacheDelete.purgeable-xpc:FF8EA9:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.718090+0000    dasd    501:com.apple.bird.sync:FAD2FA:[
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.718524+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.applessdbgrefresh.activity:7C3550:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.718935+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.metrickitd.setup:10F593:[
    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 20.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{deviceActivity == 1}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
default 16:41:10.719361+0000    dasd    0:com.apple.apsd.apprefresh:22FA84:[
    {name: PowerNapPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{(inADarkWake == 0 AND appRefresh == 1) AND wakeState == "0x1f"}]}}
    {name: ThermalPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed, Score: 0.00, Rationale: [{thermalLevel >= 1}]}}
 ], FinalDecision: Absolutely Must Not Proceed}
error   16:41:10.727170+0000    Spotify  EC3AudioFile::ParseAudioFile : ParseOneCycle failed
error   16:41:10.727181+0000    Spotify  EC3AudioFile::ParseAudioFile failed
error   16:41:10.727191+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:10.727200+0000    Spotify  Open failed
error   16:41:10.739721+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:10.739746+0000    Spotify  Open failed
error   16:41:10.745353+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:10.745373+0000    Spotify  Open failed
default 16:41:10.755062+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 5 children, _eventMask=0x48 _childEventMask=0x42 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1
default 16:41:10.763041+0000    hidd    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 4 children, _eventMask=0x42 _childEventMask=0x42 Cancel=0 Touching=1 inRange=1

error   16:41:11.748172+0000    Spotify  OpenFromDataSource failed
error   16:41:11.748188+0000    Spotify  Open failed
error   16:41:20.117057+0000    sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   16:41:20.777173+0000    sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   16:41:32.384994+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q53848] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(45) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 45 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044086533
error   16:41:33.663597+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q27839] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(66) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 66 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044087812
error   16:41:37.009325+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q27839] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(66) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 66 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044091157
error   16:41:39.959558+0000    cfprefsd    rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, alexgodbehere, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 467 (Google Chrome Helper (GPU)) because accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error   16:41:39.980318+0000    cfprefsd    rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, alexgodbehere, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 467 (Google Chrome Helper (GPU)) because accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error   16:41:39.996711+0000    cfprefsd    rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, alexgodbehere, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 467 (Google Chrome Helper (GPU)) because accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error   16:41:40.186126+0000    cfprefsd    rejecting read of { kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, alexgodbehere, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 467 (Google Chrome Helper (GPU)) because accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
error   16:41:41.383889+0000    sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   16:41:44.752353+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q6410] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(45) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 45 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044098900
error   16:41:48.092310+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q6410] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(45) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 45 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044102240
error   16:41:50.691803+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q24473] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(70) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 70 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044104839
error   16:41:51.013396+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q27839] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(66) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 66 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044105161
error   16:41:54.832345+0000    sharingd    Trying to grab power assertion while we already have one
error   16:41:58.699712+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q2673] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(70) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 70 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044112847
error   16:41:58.700217+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q650] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(72) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 72 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044112847
error   16:42:02.039763+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q2673] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(70) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 70 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044116187
error   16:42:02.040129+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q650] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(72) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 72 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044116187
error   16:42:02.099973+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q6410] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(45) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 45 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044116247
error   16:42:02.405297+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q42416] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(74) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 74 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044116553
error   16:42:02.405828+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q18363] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(81) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 81 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044116553
error   16:42:04.677923+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q19415] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(89) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 89 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044118825
error   16:42:04.678342+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q24825] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(91) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 91 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044118825
error   16:42:05.616590+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q39337] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(93) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 93 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044119764
error   16:42:05.747353+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q42416] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(74) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 74 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044119895
error   16:42:05.747808+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q18363] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(81) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 81 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044119895
error   16:42:06.560386+0000    cloudd  Connection 53: timed out with error(4:-2100)
error   16:42:06.560401+0000    cloudd  Connection 53: encountered error(4:-2100)
error   16:42:06.564575+0000    cloudd  Task <2229AEF4-8780-4F66-9892-EA88C5EE27C2>.<48> HTTP load failed, 1130/0 bytes (error code: -1001 [4:-2100])
error   16:42:06.564830+0000    cloudd  Task <2229AEF4-8780-4F66-9892-EA88C5EE27C2>.<48> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2100, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff59c617890 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<private>, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=<private>, NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=<private>, NSErrorFailingURLKey=<private>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
error   16:42:06.565072+0000    cloudd  NetworkingError NSURLErrorDomain/-1001
error   16:42:06.565665+0000    cloudd  [Request 0x7ff59c434ef0] Finishing request with error 0x7ff59c627bf0
error   16:42:07.989473+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q60206] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(95) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 95 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044122137
error   16:42:07.990345+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q22532] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(97) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 97 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044122137
error   16:42:08.022154+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q19415] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(89) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 89 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044122169
error   16:42:08.023200+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q24825] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(91) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 91 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044122169
error   16:42:08.963090+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q39337] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(93) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 93 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044123110
error   16:42:10.905659+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q25006] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(99) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 99 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044125053
error   16:42:10.906517+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q36178] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(101) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 101 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044125053
error   16:42:11.331511+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q60206] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(95) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 95 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044125479
error   16:42:11.332062+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q22532] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(97) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 97 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044125479
error   16:42:14.245069+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q25006] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(99) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 99 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044128392
error   16:42:14.245975+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q36178] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(101) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 101 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044128392
error   16:42:16.050412+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q2673] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(70) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 70 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044130197
error   16:42:16.050787+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q650] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(72) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 72 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044130197
fault   16:42:16.940850+0000    apsd    Peer connection [pid=615] lacks APSConnectionInitiateEntitlement
error   16:42:16.940953+0000    amsaccountsd    Interrupted connection to service com.apple.apsd
error   16:42:19.696962+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q32696] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(103) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 103 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044133844
error   16:42:19.755749+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q42416] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(74) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 74 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044133903
error   16:42:19.756295+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q18363] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(81) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 81 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044133903
error   16:42:22.032243+0000    mDNSResponder   [Q19415] mDNSPlatformSendUDP -> sendto(89) failed to send packet on InterfaceID 0x6 en0/6 to <private>:53 skt 89 error -1 errno 65 (No route to host) 2044136179
```

**What I've tried:**

- Removing and re-adding the wifi adapter
- Removing and re-adding the wireless network
- Trying to access the internet through a different network (4G hotspot)
- Setting DNS to `8.8.8.8`
- Adding IP reservation to the router table and renewing DHCP lease
- Reset PRAM & NVRAM

Is there any other information that I can provide to help diagnose and solve this?

Comment: Have the same issue macOS 10.15.4, after this upgrade my wifi connection drops every 2 ~ 3 hours, I need to restart my machine to get it working again, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Go in your router configuration page and select wifi connection proprieties.
Then set the bandwidth to 20 Mhz which is more stable.
By default the bandwidth should be 20/40 Mhz that can occasionally cause connection drop.

hope it help you.

Comment: It's nothing to do with my network, as the issue persists on multiple networks.